# Quick question about V-Brakes?

Tags: brakes

I'm interested in purchasing a bike, however due to my location can't get into a bike shop, so will need to order it online.

The 2009 GT 2.0 Transeo I am interested in does not explicitly say it has v-brakes. I know it is not the disk version though.

The 2010 GT 2.0 Transeo mentions it has v-brakes.

1. Is the v-brake a fairly recent improvement in rim brakes as recent as 2010?
2. I know it is common for people to assume disk brakes are better. But I'm trying to bring down the price of my purchase, and do not intend to go cycling on rough mountain paths, or do too much wet/muddy condition cycling. Which is better in your opinion for my usage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2009 edition will have 'V' brakes, although they may be called 'cantilevers' or something else that describes roughly the same thing. This is base specification for an MTB, to be assumed unless stated otherwise.

Disk brakes are better in the wet because the braking surface stays nice and dry, however, you can still stop in the wet with V brakes. We have already had this question:

[Why are disc brakes rare on road bikes?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1500/why-dont-road-bikes-have-disc-brakes/3862#3862)

Answer (score 1):

The "V-Brake" (originally a proprietary term from Shimano, but universally used now) was the replacement for the "Cantilever" brake which was generally used maybe 20 years ago.

Essentially, V-brakes are a form of cantilever brake, but they have better leverage and a simplified alignment system.  Keeping "cantis" aligned was...Annoying,  (however, they did last a long time)
V-Brakes are fine.  They are powerful enough to lock wheels if you want to, easy to maintain, and replacement pads are readily available.   They do tend to have shorter life, however.

Comment: Shorter life and more power, but far less control of that power, compared to either canti's or discs.